# Scrape HTML before submitting page in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, race-condition

I need to grab the HTML of the current page and submit it via a form. A simplified version of my page looks like this:

```
<body>
    <div id="container">
        <!-- stuff here -->
        <form id="pageform" action="mypage.php" method="post">
            <input type="hidden" id="Source" />
            <button type="submit" name="submit">Submit</button>
        </form>
    </div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function handlesubmit() {
            var pageSource = $("#container").html();
            $("#Source").val(pageSource);

            return true;
        }

        $(function() {
            $("#pageform").submit(handlesubmit);
        });
    </script>
</body>
```

This code works fine in Internet Explorer 9, Firefox and Chrome. In Internet Explorer 7 and Internet Explorer 8, though, the resulting value of `Source` is truncated on the server-side (the source is fairly large). I was able to fix this by changing the form submission to take place via `$.post()` instead.

Why does this work using a jQuery Ajax post and not regular form submission? Is there a race condition caused by a the form submitting before the value of `Source` is set? Which parts of the above code happen asynchronously - only the `$.post()` request?

UPDATE: The request is performed via POST, not GET.

Comment: Are you sure the method on the form was a post and not a get?

Comment: Yes I made sure to use $.post().

Comment: No, that's not what I asked. I'm asking if the method on the form was get to begin.... You've already made 2 typos, it's not an unreasonable question.

Comment: Yeap, it is post on the form, and the code that 'works' uses $.post()

Comment: @Harper Google for "IE7 bug post request". Your provided information is not sufficient to offer the right answer at once.

Comment: Is the truncated value always a consistent length? If so, I suspect something else is going on. If it's inconsistent, maybe there is some value in your race condition theory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there is no race condition. The query string is simply limited in length. If you are sending large amount of data, then you are supposed to use the POST method (which will put data into the request body).